# Preventing an infinite loop in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am just learning neo4j and was making something similiar to an organization hierarchy where a person has a manager who has a manager who has a manager and so on.

At first I used the assumptoin that the owner of the company would have no manager and got my needs working to show myself and management all the up to the owner.

To solve this I used the following query which works for my simple needs.

```
MATCH(baseEmployee:Employee)-[:MANAGEDBY*0..]->(manager) 
where baseEmployee.Name = 'Josh'
RETURN manager.Name;
```

But what would happen if the boss had manager set to himself.  To my understanding this will cause an infinite loop.

How would I prevent the match from following the MANAGEDBY path if the manager = currentEmployee?

Answer (score 9):

This will not result in an infinite loop. You have to be aware of a very important concept of a path - this is what you specfic with the `MATCH` statement:

A path might contain loops (aka the same node multiple times) but it will never use the same relationship twice. Therefore even if the boss' manager is himself this will not cause infinite loops.

Comment: Correct. [The neo4j manual](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/cypherdoc-uniqueness.html) states:
`While pattern matching, Cypher makes sure to not include matches where the same graph relationship is found multiple times in a single pattern. `.